# saveEventually doesn't work with DefaultACL

Tags: parse-platform

So this is a weird one. I had my application working just fine saving objects locally using pinInBackground, then remotely using saveEventually. I then decided to add ACLs and anonymous users, and saveEventually stopped pushing my objects remotely. In 100% of the cases, even with full wifi connectivity, my objects are no longer getting saved to Parse. I added a SaveCallback and it is never getting called.

> ```
>     final Person p = new Person(firstName, lastName, dateTime, phoneNumber);
>     p.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
>         @Override
>         public void done(ParseException e) {
>             if (e == null) {
>                 Log.d("AddPerson", "Saved locally, attempting to store remotely....");
>                 p.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void done(ParseException e) {
>                         if (e==null) {
>                             Log.d("AddPerson", "Saved remotely, all done.");
>                         } else {
>                             Log.d("AddPerson", e.getMessage());
>                         }
>                     }
>                 });
>             } else {
>                 Log.d("AddPerson", e.getMessage());
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

The message "saved remotely" never gets called, nor are the objects visible using the data browser. If i change saveEventually to saveInBackground() everything works fine right away and saves remotely.

My code for ACLs are anonymous users is:

```
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(new ParseACL(), true);
        ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d("Main", "Anonymous login failed.");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Main", "Anonymous user logged in: " + ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
                }
            }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please open an official bug report at https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Which category should the bug be filed under? There is no option for Parse in the report a bug screen.

Comment: Edit: Figured out the Parse category doesn't show up unless you go through the Parse site https://parse.com/help#report

Comment: woops... ok, yeah that's the right link.

Comment: Has this been solved? I'm facing the same problem, plus saveInBackground is only able to push once. Second time stucks forever.