# cannot add column with 'put' method in Parse database

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, database-connection

I'm developing real-time messenger application with Parse and want to display all of users in ListView. So I also want to reference if user is online or offline, I tried 'put' method to add column named "online" and put information about it. When it went wrong, I added that column myself, but it still did not work. Here it's what I tried in UserList class at all:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserList extends AppCompatActivity {
     public static ArrayList<ParseUser> userList;
     public static String TAG = "UserList";
     public static ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
    updateUserStatus(true);

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    updateUserStatus(false);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadUserList();
}
private void updateUserStatus(boolean isOnline) {
    user.put("online", isOnline);
    user.saveEventually();
    //System.out.println("getBoolean's result : " + user.getBoolean("online"));
}
private void loadUserList() {
    ParseUser.getQuery().whereNotEqualTo("username", user.getUsername()).findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (objects != null) {
                if (objects.size() == 0) System.out.println("No user found");
                userList = new ArrayList<>(objects);
                ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
                list.setAdapter(new UserAdapter(UserList.this));
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(UserList.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("exception detected while loading user list");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

UserAdapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static String TAG = "UserAdapter";
    public TextView labelname;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public UserAdapter(Context context){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return UserList.userList.size();
}
@Override
public ParseUser getItem(int index) {
    return UserList.userList.get(index);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    return index;
}
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup group) {
       ParseUser c = getItem(pos);
        if (v == null) {
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
        }
        labelname = (TextView) v;
        labelname.setText(c.getUsername());
        labelname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(c.getBoolean("online") ? R.drawable.ic_online
                : R.drawable.ic_offline, 0, R.drawable.arrow, 0);

    return v;
   }
}
```

I tried saveInBackground with SaveCallback, but it throws exception named:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first

But I'm puzzled more than I was 1 hour ago. I authorize my user in another class and it seems not to be problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was open bug of `Parse`. might be possible that not solved yet. [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857301/saveeventually-doesnt-work-with-defaultacl) and [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-saveeventually-not-saving-eventually-until-after-app-reset) too.

instead of `saveEventually()` use `saveInBackground()`

and

you can't do like that

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
```

if you want logged user than get like this

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

and before getting logged user you must do sign up

Comment: So, what should I do now? I looked at messenger's demo based on Parse and it was using the 'put' method,it worked fine. I'm pretty puzzled.

Comment: you can use `saveInBackground()`

Comment: You mean "user.saveInBackground();" after calling 'put' method,yes? I'll try it.

Comment: It isn't working. I tried it and with SaveCallback,too. But it throws exception and I will edit my post to show you that.

Comment: God, it works! Thank you. I'll comment if something goes wrong about it.